# Access Update Query w/ Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery

My Attempt:

```
UPDATE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]
(
SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID], [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[dBranch] AS Branch, [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[dBranch] & " Shared Appropriation" AS [Shared Appropriation]

FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]

WHERE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID] In

  (
    SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
    FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]
    GROUP BY [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
    HAVING
      (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="Navy")
        AND
      (Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="USMC"))
      OR
      ((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="USMC")
        AND 
      (Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="Navy")))
  )
;) AS SATable
SET [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Shared Appropriation] = SATable.[Shared Appropriation]
Where [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID] = SATable.[Journal Voucher ID], [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[dBranch] = SATable.[Branch];
```

My Goal is to update the [Shared Appropriation] column in the [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] with the concatenation of the [dBranch] field and " Shared Appropriation" from my query (that works):

```
SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].*
FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]

WHERE ((([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]) In (SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]
GROUP BY [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
HAVING (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))="Navy") AND ((Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))="USMC")) OR (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))="USMC") AND ((Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))="Navy"));)));
```

My thought is to create an alias, SATable, for the working query and throw it into an update query.

Comment: what happens when you add a comma after `UPDATE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]`, i.e. `UPDATE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE], (SELECT [DATA .....`?

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt - is it syntax error - or does it not update correctly?

Comment: @cha After that I get "Syntax Error in From Clause"

Comment: @dbmitch (without the comma/as posted) I get "Syntax Error in Update Statement"

Comment: What's the purpose of the second query? How is related to your update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be re-written to this:

```
UPDATE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]
SET [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Shared Appropriation] = [dBranch] & " Shared Appropriation"
Where [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID] IN
  (
    SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
    FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]
    GROUP BY [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]
    HAVING
      (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="Navy")
        AND
      (Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="USMC"))
      OR
      ((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="USMC")
        AND 
      (Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch)="Navy")))
  )
```